# Automatic Login with facebook using a subdomain from My App

Tags: facebook, vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, multi-tenant, facebook-messenger

I know this is an old answer but I think the context is different for my use case.

I am trying to log in with Facebook and in the configuration of my application in Facebook I have my web application. For example the URL of the site I have is website.com. However, I am actually using subdomains, in this way, my application generates subdomains belonging to my clients. For example, the URL of my client in my application
to login is: subdomain1.website.com The error message I get from Facebook is:

`JSSDK Unknown Host domain: The domain where you host the Facebook Javascript SDK is not in the list of host domains in your app's Javascript SDK. Specify your host domain in the app dashboard login settings.`

How can I login with Facebook using a subdomain? Obviously, I don't want to add the sub-domains every time a new customer comes to my application.

Pd: I thought that with adding to Allowed Domains for the SDK for JavaScript *.website.com
but that doesn't work.
I hope your answers, thank you.

Comment: Either list all subdomains. Or send all sites to login.website.com for logging in and then send them back to the right subdomain after.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with list all subdomains? I will try to do login.website.com and inform you. Thank you very much for your prompt reply. @WizKid

Comment: I mean add every single subdomain like you said you didn't want to do.